# Looking for list of ships and passenger lists from Dutch Guiana to Rhode Island around 1756

Tags: manifest, ship, guyana, rhode-island, 1750s

I am looking for list of ships and passenger lists from Dutch Guiana to Rhode Island around 1756.  I could use some insight into major US port that was used by ships from there.  I’ve scoured ancestry but no match so far for my ancestor.  I believe the major port was Georgetown Guiana at that time.